# How to get an C# Enum in an interface act like a C one?

Tags: c#, interface, enums

I am used to enums in C, still a bit confused about how they are treated in C#.  I want to implement an interface in C# that looks like

```
enum foo {
  one,
  two 
}

interface Ibar {
  enum foo {get;}
}
```

where the class that implements interface Ibar will return either foo.one or foo.two when the property foo is gotten.  So, for example

```
class bar : Ibar {
  enum foo {
    get { return foo.one; }
  }
}
```

and can so I can do

```
bar b = new bar;
if (b.foo == foo.one) {... }
```

The above interface code expects me to define the enum inside the interface (it says the ';' should be a ',').

The closest post I could find that was relevant is http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/524824-enum-property-interface but the enum is defined inside the class.

Comment: Not very clear what the problem is. An error message might help us understand

Comment: @mihai - see the answers below for clarification on the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the syntax you want is like this:

```
enum Foo
{
    One,
    Two 
}

interface IBar
{
    Foo Foo { get; }
}
```

The result is an interface with a property named `Foo` of type `Foo`.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax you want is:

```
enum foo { one, two }

interface Ibar { foo foo { get; } }

class bar : Ibar { foo foo { get { return foo.one; } } }
```

You only use `enum` to *define* a new enum; when creating a member variable, you use the *name* of the enum you've created.

However, you'd be much better off not naming the member variable the same as the enum type:

```
enum FooEnum { One, Two }

interface IBar { FooEnum FooValue { get; } }

class Bar : IBar { FooEnum FooValue { get { return FooEnum.one; } } }
```

(Note I've only used `Enum` and `Value` to clarify which is the enum type and which is the value, don't do this.)

(Also, I think that's more like the usual C# casing conventions.)

Comment: I don't agree with your second version. Don't put Enum in the name of the enum. That is redundant. Naming the property like the type is perfectly legal and is in no way a problem.

Comment: @Daniel I agree, I was just trying to make a distinction between the enum _type_ and the _member_. I guess in some cases having them the same might even be appropriate, but without knowing what the enum is meant to represent it's hard to tell.